# Custom post permalinks for specific categories

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have specific categories posts where i want to remove category name from URL.

My current post link is: https://example.com/my_cat_name/post_name/
I want: https://example.com/post_name/

But only for specific categories. Other categories should not been modified.

This code helps me to change permalinks for posts

```
add_filter('post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3);
function custom_permalink($permalink, $post, $leavename)
{
    
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);

    if (!empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_ID == 4) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit(home_url('/' . $post->post_name . '/'));
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Links already changed as i want, but i cant open the post pages, i have 404 error.

I think i need some rewrite_rules, but i cant figure out.

If adding this code:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules()
{
   
  
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([^/]+)/?', 
        'index.php?category_name=my_cat_name&name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

}
```

Short links is ok, but all other pages is 404. Please help me

Comment: that regex is incredibly ambiguous, if you only want it to match `my_cat_name` shouldn't it contain `my_cat_name` in the regex? You want it to match only the URLs you're interested in, but that regex will match all of them

Comment: @TomJNowell my_cat_name is a variable which i geting from the database, and there can be many cat_names...

Comment: I see, you still need a way to write a regex that can take in a string and matches _only_ those URLs that you want it to match, it cannot match everything otherwise.. it will match everything which is your problem. Note though that WP should happily accept `/post-name` for all posts regardless of wether you want a category in front, it will just redirect to the _canonical_ URL when the user arrives. Not being aware of this means you're probably going to run headfirst into this if you did find a solution only to see WP redirect `/my-post/` to `/cat-name/my-post` anyway

Comment: also, if you did get what you wanted via a rewrite rule, in addition to the canonical URLs no longer matching and redirecitng, the sitemap would point to the original URLs, not your short versions. So if you were doing this for SEO reasons Google wouldn't even see your new URLs, and WP would automatically use the long URLs in menus and widgets. For these reasons, a rewrite rule may not be the best approach